# phpBB Password Authentication on Custom Site

Tags: authentication, passwords, phpbb

I have been looking for the past few hours on how to user the phpBB login script on a custom site.  I think I'm just not searching for the right things.

A while ago, I created a phpBB site and have over 900 members registered through phpBB.  I am currently face-lifting this site and redoing the user registration along with all of the other custom code I have.

My problem is, I want the users to be able to log in as usual, though I want to input them into my new database so everything can run smoothly.  I mainly need their username, password and old ID#, but **I don't know how to use phpBB's password authentication or where to find it**

The statement needs to look something like this:

```
On Login, grab username and password variables:
    if the username is not in MY database, check phpBB database.  
        If the username is in phpBB database, check to see if the password is correct **(This is the part I don't know how to do)**
            If the password is correct, input the username, user ID and the password (encrypted my way) into MY database
                Login
            If the password is incorrect - error
        if the username is NOT in phpBB database - continue
    if the username is not in MY database - input username and encrypted pass into my DB
        login
```

Where can I find a script to authenticate the phpBB user's passwords?  I don't care how the script is done, I know that's a secret, I just need to be able to authenticate passwords so that I can make sure it's the same user

I do have access to the phpBB database, I just need a way to authenticate their password

Answer (score 0):

I would rather delete the quesion, but here's the answer:

Check here: http://sunnyis.me/blog/secure-passwords/

and when you download the PasswordHash.php, change all of the $P$ to $H$.  It will work.  Strange how it creates a password, every time it creates, it's different.  But the CHECK part of it makes sure it checks it correctly, no matter what hashed pass it creates.